# SQL: join tables with valid from / valid to fields

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, date-range

I'm faced to a very generic issue in our Postgresql database. Many tables contain entries that are only valid for a period of time, for instance the details of contracts that are likely to evolve over time.

In order to deal with it, two fields, `valid from` and `valid to`, are provided to indicate the validity period of the row content. Each time a contract changes, a row is added to the table with the actualized information and the corresponding valid dates.

The main deal arises when performing joins on tables with overlapping validity fields. More precisely, given a first table:

```sql
fg     valid_from    valid_to    attr_table1
key1   2020-01-01   2020-01-18        A
key1   2020-01-19   null              B
key2   2020-01-01   2020-01-30        A
key2   2020-01-30   null              B
```

and a second table

```sql
fg     valid_from    valid_to    attr_table2
key1   2020-01-01   2020-01-10       1.0
key1   2020-01-10   null             3.0
key2   2020-01-01   2020-01-30      10.0
key2   2020-01-30   null            11.0
```

I want to build a joined table with a validity field that embedds the validity periods of both tables, such as:

```sql
fg     valid_from   valid_to    attr_table1  attr_table2
key1   2020-01-01   2020-01-10        A         1.0
key1   2020-01-10   2020-01-18        A         3.0
key1   2020-01-18   null              B         3.0
key2   2020-01-01   2020-01-30        A         10.0
key2   2020-01-30   null              B         11.0
```

Until now, my most convincing attempt was to switch to the Postgresql-specific type `daterange`, and use the `&&` operator ("have common points"). I concatenated both `valid from` and `valid to` fields into a `validity` field, and next query almost seems to do the job:

```sql
select t1.fg,
       (case when upper(t1.validity) is null
             then case when (upper(t2.validity) is null) 
                       then case when lower(t1.validity) > lower(t2.validity) 
                                 then daterange(lower(t1.validity), null)
                                 else daterange(lower(t2.validity), null)
                                 end
                       else case when lower(t1.validity) > lower(t2.validity) 
                                 then daterange(lower(t1.validity), upper(t2.validity)) 
                                 else daterange(lower(t2.validity), upper(t2.validity)) 
                                 end
                       end
             when upper(t2.validity) is null
             then case when (upper(t1.validity) is null) 
                       then case when lower(t1.validity) > lower(t2.validity) 
                                 then daterange(lower(t1.validity), null)
                                 else daterange(lower(t2.validity), null)
                                 end
                       else case when lower(t1.validity) > lower(t2.validity) 
                                 then daterange(lower(t1.validity), upper(t1.validity)) 
                                 else daterange(lower(t2.validity), upper(t1.validity)) 
                                 end
                       end
             when lower(t1.validity) <= lower(t2.validity)
             then case when upper(t1.validity) >= upper(t2.validity) 
                       then daterange(lower(t2.validity), upper(t2.validity))
                       else daterange(lower(t2.validity), upper(t1.validity))
                       end
             else case when upper(t1.validity) >= upper(t2.validity) 
                       then daterange(lower(t1.validity), upper(t2.validity))
                       else daterange(lower(t1.validity), upper(t1.validity))
                       end
             end
            ) as validity,
       t1.attr_table1, 
       t2.attr_table2
  from table1 as t1 
       join table2 as t2
         on t1.fg = t2.fg
        and t1.validity && t2.validity
order by fg, validity
```

However, this query fails when the starting point of the first table does not match any entry in the second one. For instance, with an additional row in the first and second tables like

In table 1:

`key1   2019-12-25   2020-01-01        A`

In table 2:

`key1   2019-12-27   2020-01-01       -1`

The resulting first row of the output table is

`key1   2019-12-27   2020-01-01        A    -1`

instead of

```
key1   2019-12-25   2019-12-27        A    null
key1   2019-12-27   2020-01-01        A    -1
```

Is anyone aware of a better approach ?

EDIT: The code to create table1 and table2, relying on daterange:

```sql
create table table1
( 
  fg text, 
  validity daterange, 
  attr_table1 text
);
insert into table1 
values
('key1', daterange('2020-01-01', '2020-01-18'),  'A'),
('key1', daterange('2020-01-18', null        ),  'B'),
('key2', daterange('2020-01-01', '2020-01-30'),  'A'),
('key2', daterange('2020-01-30', null        ),  'B')
```

and

```sql
create table table2
( 
  fg text, 
  validity daterange,  
  attr_table2 text
);
insert into table2 
values
('key1', daterange('2020-01-01', '2020-01-10'),   1.0),
('key1', daterange('2020-01-10', null        ),   3.0),
('key2', daterange('2020-01-01', '2020-01-30'),  10.0),
('key2', daterange('2020-01-30', null        ),  11.0)
```

Comment: Can you please post create table and inserts or create an sqlfiddle so that we can work with your data?

Comment: You can simplify your case switch part by using [range_merge](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-range.html#RANGE-FUNCTIONS-TABLE)

Comment: @NuLo, you're right, I added the create table and inserts, using the daterange functions.

Comment: Will each key have the same valid_from date in its first row in each table?  For example, key1 starts from 2020-01-01 in both tables, but is it possible that the first row in table2 to be 2020-01-02 instead?

Comment: @MatBailie, yes, different keys can have different starting dates, and the same key can have different starting dates in the two tables. That's a real issue with the approach I came up with. The && operator has trouble to merge the first rows as I wish, if the starting date is not the same..

Comment: Can there ever be a gap?  If one row for a key has and end date, will the next row for that key ***always*** have a from date that matches?

Comment: @MatBailie, we can assume there is no gap. I believe handling this case adds complexity. Moreover, I guess some kind of preprocessing to fill gaps with null could be possible.

Comment: Your sample data has an end date of 18th January, yet the next row starts on 19th.  I believe of of those two dates is a typo.

Comment: Note: you could simplify your logic by setting `valid_to = inf` instead of `valid_to = NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATE]

- make a calendar table of all existing timespans per `fg`
- LEFT join both table1 and table2 to this table
- [for ease of comparison I changed the `valid_to` NULLs to `infinity`]

---

```
create table table1
(
  fg text,
  validity daterange,
  attr_table1 text
);

insert into table1
values
('key1', daterange('2019-12-25', '2020-01-01'),  'A'), -- NEW
('key1', daterange('2020-01-01', '2020-01-18'),  'A'),
('key1', daterange('2020-01-19', 'infinity'        ),  'B'),
('key2', daterange('2020-01-01', '2020-01-30'),  'A'),
('key2', daterange('2020-01-30', 'infinity'        ),  'B');

create table table2
(
  fg text,
  validity daterange,
  attr_table2 text
);
insert into table2
values
('key1', daterange('2019-12-27', '2020-01-01'),  -1  ), -- NEW
('key1', daterange('2020-01-01', '2020-01-10'),   1.0),
('key1', daterange('2020-01-10', 'infinity'        ),   3.0),
('key2', daterange('2020-01-01', '2020-01-30'),  10.0),
('key2', daterange('2020-01-30', 'infinity'        ),  11.0);


        -- Make a 'CALENDAR' table with all points in time (per fg)
        -- ---------------------------------------------------------
WITH pits AS (
        select distinct fg, lower(validity) as pit FROM table1
UNION
        select distinct fg, upper(validity) as pit FROM table1
UNION
        select distinct fg, lower(validity) as pit FROM table2
UNION
        select distinct fg, upper(validity) as pit FROM table2
        )
        -- combine all adjacent PITs to ranges
        -- ---------------------------------------
, pairs AS (
        SELECT fg, pit AS opit
        , lead(pit) OVER (PARTITION BY fg ORDER BY pit) AS npit
        from pits
        )
        -- Make dateranges from them
        -- --------------------------
, tablex AS (
        SELECT fg
        , daterange(opit,npit) AS validity
        FROM pairs
        WHERE npit IS NOT NULL
        -- ORDER BY 1,2;
        )
        -- Left join both table1 and table2 to all_rages
        -- ----------------------------------------------
SELECT tx.fg
        , tx.validity
        , t1.validity * t2.validity AS overlapped
        , t1.attr_table1
        , t2.attr_table2
FROM tablex tx
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.fg = tx.fg AND t1.validity && tx.validity
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.fg = tx.fg AND t2.validity && tx.validity
ORDER BY 1,2
        ;
```

---

Results:

---

```
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 5
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 5
  fg  |        validity         |       overlapped        | attr_table1 | attr_table2 
------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+-------------
 key1 | [2019-12-25,2019-12-27) |                         | A           | 
 key1 | [2019-12-27,2020-01-01) | [2019-12-27,2020-01-01) | A           | -1
 key1 | [2020-01-01,2020-01-10) | [2020-01-01,2020-01-10) | A           | 1.0
 key1 | [2020-01-10,2020-01-18) | [2020-01-10,2020-01-18) | A           | 3.0
 key1 | [2020-01-18,2020-01-19) |                         |             | 3.0
 key1 | [2020-01-19,infinity)   | [2020-01-19,infinity)   | B           | 3.0
 key2 | [2020-01-01,2020-01-30) | [2020-01-01,2020-01-30) | A           | 10.0
 key2 | [2020-01-30,infinity)   | [2020-01-30,infinity)   | B           | 11.0
(8 rows)
```

Comment: I think this does not answer the second part of the question and it is only a simplification of the original query

Answer (score 1):

Rushing to next meeting, will write an explanation later, but for now...

- mostly relies on there not being any gaps between rows
- also relies on the values of attrib1 or attrib2 never being null (nulls get replaced with previous not null values)

Giving...

```
with
  combined AS
(
  select fg, lower(validity) AS valid_from, attr_table1, NULL as attr_table2 from table1
  union all
  select fg, lower(validity) AS valid_from, NULL AS attr_table1, attr_table2 from table2
),
  aggregated AS
(
  select
    fg,
    valid_from,
    max(attr_table1)  as attr_table1,
    max(attr_table2)  as attr_table2,
    count(max(attr_table1)) over (partition by fg order by valid_from) attrib1_grp,
    count(max(attr_table2)) over (partition by fg order by valid_from) attrib2_grp
  from
    combined
  group by
    fg,
    valid_from
)
SELECT
  fg,
  valid_from,
  lead(valid_from) over (partition by fg order by valid_from)  as valid_to,
  max(attr_table1) over (partition by fg, attrib1_grp)         as attr_table1,
  max(attr_table2) over (partition by fg, attrib2_grp)         as attr_table2
from
  aggregated
order by
  fg,
  valid_from
```

demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7d97c9623e5f9efb4d729775ff61e7b5

---

***EDIT:***

The above code relies on the premise that if a key's attribute changes in ***either*** table, the result set needs a change on that date too.

This means that we can just union the two tables' keeping only the valid_from, and calculate the valid_to using `LEAD()` *(which will sometimes pick up the valid_from from the same table, sometimes from the other table)*.

That leaves a bunch of nulls in the attribute columns.  If `attrib1` changes, `attrib2` will be `NULL` in the unioned set, and vice versa.

What is needed to fill those nulls in, is to look back through the new time series to find the most recent `NOT NULL` value for that attribute.  As `LAST_VALUE()` doesn't have a `SKIP NULLS` option, I rolled my own...

- have a cumulative counter for how many times the attribute has been `NOT NULL`, and use that as a group identifier
- by definition, the first attribute in the group will be `NOT NULL`, and all the rows will be `NULL`
- So, taking `MAX(attribute)` for the group allows me to get the previous `NOT NULL` value for all of the `NULL` rows

This demo makes it a little easier to see the calculations happening...

- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a25459b60bc875e47f6311f79d0ce9ba

---

***EDIT:***

I *think* this now works with gaps (where the attribute is *implicitly* set to `NULL`) and rows where the attribute is *explicitly* set to `NULL`...

- assumes that no two rows (same key, same table) start on the same date

  - if that happens, the attribute picks the MAX() value for that date
- assumes that no row can start before a previous row (same key, same table) has ended

  - if that happens, gibberish gets returned

(Though I advise more rigorous testing...)

```
with
  combined(
    fg, valid_from, attr_table1, attr_table2, atrib1_set, atrib2_set
  ) AS
(
  select fg, lower(validity), attr_table1, NULL       , 1, NULL::int from table1
  union all
  select fg, upper(validity), NULL,        NULL       , 1, NULL::int from table1
  union all
  select fg, lower(validity), NULL       , attr_table2, NULL, 1 from table2
  union all
  select fg, upper(validity), NULL       , NULL       , NULL, 1 from table2
),
  aggregated AS
(
  select
    fg,
    valid_from,
    max(attr_table1)  as attr_table1,
    max(attr_table2)  as attr_table2,
    count(max(atrib1_set)) over (partition by fg order by valid_from) attrib1_grp,
    count(max(atrib2_set)) over (partition by fg order by valid_from) attrib2_grp
  from
    combined
  where
    valid_from is not null
  group by
    fg,
    valid_from
)
SELECT
  fg,
  valid_from,
  lead(valid_from) over (partition by fg order by valid_from)  as valid_to,
  max(attr_table1) over (partition by fg, attrib1_grp)         as attr_table1,
  max(attr_table2) over (partition by fg, attrib2_grp)         as attr_table2
from
  aggregated
order by
  fg,
  valid_from
```

Demo:

- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=20ed6974aace9ec52535d78c36594e9f